# Writing masked portion of an image to a different matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have  masked two portion of an image.I want to write the two masked portion to a separate matrix.The code is as shown below.

```
 Image1=double(imread('obtained_output.jpg'));
 Image2=double(imread('reference_output.jpg')); 
[M,N]=size(Image1);
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(uint8(Image1));
mask = zeros(M, N);
mask(1:120, 1:100) = 1;
mask(180:300,1:100)=1;
subplot(2, 2, 2);
imshow((mask));
subplot(2,2,3);
obtained_mask=Image1.*mask;
imshow(uint8(obtained_mask));
subplot(2,2,4);
 reference_mask=Image2.*mask;
 imshow(uint8(reference_mask));
```

Can anyone help me to get a solution.I think of doing concatenation of the masked portion.But no clear idea

Comment: This is your actual mask or just some example? If this is your mask than just extract portion of images without the mask:  `Mtx1 = Image1(1:100, 1:100); Mtx2 = Image1(175:300,1:100);`. The same for Image2.

Comment: @kadu Did you get the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @Marcin thank you for the answer.i extracted the two portions and concatenated the two portions and got the result.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple independent regions in a binary image can be separated with [`bwconncomp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) (black/white connected components):

```
>> CC = bwconncomp(mask)
CC = 
    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [320 320]
      NumObjects: 2
    PixelIdxList: {[12000x1 double]  [12100x1 double]}
```

It indicates that you have `NumObjects=2` regions, for which the non-zero pixel locations are stored in each cell of `PixelIdxList`.  Use this data to make separate logical masks for each distinct region. With [`labelmatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/labelmatrix.html):

```
L = labelmatrix(CC);
mask1 = L==1;
mask2 = L==2;
```

Or manually, if you prefer:

```
mask1 = false(size(mask));
mask1(CC.PixelIdxList{1}) = true;
mask2 = false(size(mask));
mask2(CC.PixelIdxList{2}) = true;
```

NOTE: `bwconncomp` is the new way to do this, although the function [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) is still available, which can also give you these masks (with less memory efficiency).